# How to: Create trigger for auto update modified date with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, triggers

It would be nice to know how to create a trigger that auto-updates the `modifiedDate` column in my SQL Server table:

Table **TimeEntry**

```
Id (PK)
UserId (FK)
Description
Time
GenDate
ModDate
```

Trigger code:

```
+   TR_TimeEntry_UpdateModDate()
+   TR_TimeEntry_InsertGenDate()
```

An example for update `ModDate` would be nice.

Comment: Does it have to be a trigger?

Comment: why dont you set the column value to TR_TimeEntry_UpdateModDate() = GetDate()
whenever you update ?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

My approach:

- define a **default constraint** on the `ModDate` column with a value of `GETDATE()` - this handles the `INSERT` case
- have a `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to update the `ModDate` column

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateTimeEntry
ON dbo.TimeEntry
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE dbo.TimeEntry
    SET ModDate = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM Inserted)
```

Comment: Also it's worth considering `getUtcDate()` depending on your timezone requirements.

Comment: And if anyone was wondering, like me, whether this will recursively call itself, there's a RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS database option that you'd normally have off which prevents a trigger like this from calling itself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx

Comment: I didn't get it. I should do `SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` to `ON` or `OFF` to prevent this?

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa - I know it's late but you want it OFF. Otherwise the trigger call itself after the update it just executed.

Comment: Where does the variable `Inserted` come from?

Comment: @4ndro1d: `Inserted` and `Deleted` are two pseudo tables that always exist inside each trigger. They represented the newly inserted or the deleted rows that caused the trigger to fire - and in the case of an `UPDATE`, `Inserted` contains the new value *after* the `UPDATE` operation, while `Deleted` has the old values *before* the update

Comment: For those who have used this in a production environment. Do you notice any performance degradation? I'm weighing this option against the script-based approach for a system I'm currently designing.

Comment: Updating modified date via code is it faster then updating it via the trigger?

Comment: Why do you have to do a DISTINCT?

Comment: @Mideus: if you have a different answer - please post it as such - don't just "hijack" my response and totally change its intent !

Comment: Run `SELECT  name, is_recursive_triggers_on FROM sys.databases` to check if recursive triggers are enabled

Comment: @ΕГИІИО it is not required