# SQL Server & EF: How to have a computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, calculated-columns

I would like to have a field which is updated on every change(insertion, modification), basically, it's a "ModificationDate".

I saw there is a "Computed" StoreGeneratedPattern in EF. But since this will not set the date but only take the value generated by the database, I need to know what should I do on the database to have this default value set at the equivalent of `GetDate()` on every modification/insertion?

Comment: Almost duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737945/how-to-create-trigger-for-auto-update-modified-date-with-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create either `INSTEAD OF` update [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) where you get data and perform update yourselves or `AFTER UPDATE` trigger where you execute one more update to set the date.

It would be easier to override `SaveChanges` and set the date in your application prior to saving to database.

Comment: Seriously? There is a "Computed Column Specification", with a Formula and a IsPersisted in the table designer. I saw this Computed StoreGeneratedPattern as correct answer in a MCTS exam, so I think it's the better way

Comment: The `StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed` only tells EF that database is generated in the database so it doesn't send a value and queries the value after update but you must do the generation in the database.

Comment: Yeah I know, but what is this "Computed column specification" if it cannot be used to indicate how to generate this column?

Comment: But the purpose of computed column in table design is to compute some value based on other columns.