# Data Type that automatically stores the DateTime of the last transaction done, SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to add a new column to an existing table, so that whenever a new row is added, or an existing row is edited, this column will be filled with the exact date and time of the transaction. I tried using TimeStamp but apparently TimeStamp it has nothing to do with Date time

> It's just a binary representation of a consecutive number - it's only good for making sure a row hasn't change since it's been read. (Quoted from [How to convert SQL Server's timestamp column to datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format)

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: The answer depends on the database software you are using.  Please specify yours.

Comment: what's wrong with poor old [Datetime data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Comment: I need it to be automatic, depending on the Server time

Comment: create a default of getdate() (and a trigger for updates) and be done with it :-).

Comment: @Marian, Thanks for you comment, but this will need to be written in every insert/update query I make. I need it to be automatic pretty much like the "TimeStamp" data type

Comment: @user1010572 for the insert will be the default, for the update the trigger. There's no default population for any data type. You need to do some work.

Comment: This may be splitting hairs for your purposes, but the date/time populated by a default constraint or a trigger isn't necessarily the time of "the last transaction" (which I take to mean the time the transaction commits). Off the top of my head, the latter is only possible to retrieve using CDC (see my related answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34087/2718)). Which do you want?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to create a trigger to populate/update this new column.  See the following: [How to: Create trigger for auto update modified date with SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737945/how-to-create-trigger-for-auto-update-modified-date-with-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a trigger on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` for the table and in the trigger you can use

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET myColumn = GETDATE()
```

Your trigger should look somethign like

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_updateTimestamp
ON myTable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE myTable
    SET myColumn = GETDATE()
    WHERE ID = 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_myTable_myColumn] DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [myColumn]
GO
```

... and a good practice is to have an extra column for edited date, and update using a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_updateMyTable
ON myTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
BEGIN
    IF ΝΟΤ EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE myTable 
        SET myEditColumn = GETDATE()
        WHERE ID IN (
            SELECT
                ID
            FROM INSERTED
        )
    END
END
```