# Update database records automatically in ASP .NET project

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to update database records/ call some ASP .Net methods daily at one particular time automatically in our ASP .Net live project..

Is there any possibility to do it..??

Any body please help me to do...

Comment: yea, there is a possibility. have you tried any code to do it?

Comment: u can do it with AJAX.

Comment: you need to use sql trigger,look [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737945/how-to-create-trigger-for-auto-update-modified-date-with-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usin asp.net you can not automatically update database tables. Because to run that page you have to call that page from browser.

Instead of that you can create Window Service that call automatically on certain time. And  you can load that service to your like project IIS and that will call automatically in certain interval and perform database performance on that.

Thank you.