# Define modified value on a table automatically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following columns on a MSSQL 2014 database table:

```
Created datetime not null
  constraint DF_Post_Created default getutcdate(),  
Modified datetime not null
```

Can I make Modified to change every time the row is updated?

I think default getutcdate is only for when the row is created, right?

Comment: You need to use an update trigger for that. Usually, it's more reasonable to simply always update it manually, though (just add `Modified = getutcdate()` to all your updates).

Comment: default will work on inserting new records.. You need to use tringgers

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737945/how-to-create-trigger-for-auto-update-modified-date-with-sql-server-2008