# Need an Idea for create Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite, triggers

I have one Field Modified On with datetime datatype in sql Table.And the Field is not null.

I need to create trigger for update the Modified on Field while the record will created.

How can I do this??

Comment: If you just want to set the date on insert (record creation) then you can use a default value GETDATE() for the modified column. (MS SQL Server)

Comment: @Tjasun I Add Getdate() in default Value or binding. It was working when i create the record.But If I modified the data the Modified column doesn't change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737945/how-to-create-trigger-for-auto-update-modified-date-with-sql-server-2008

Comment: Why do you think you need a trigger? Doesn't a default value of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP work?